A question regarding weak Whitney embedding theorem
The weak Whitney embedding theorem states that any continuous map $f: D^n \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ (Let us focus on $D^n$ for this question) can be approximated (in $C^0$-norm) by embeddings. A counter example for $D^n\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be constructed as follows. We can take
$$D_1 = (\text{unit ball in }\mathbb{R^n})\times \{\vec{0}\} \text{ and } D_2 = \{\vec{0}\}\times(\text{unit ball in }\mathbb{R^n}).$$
The two $n$-balls intersect at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and this intersection cannot be removed by perturbation. ($\partial D_1$ and $\partial D_2$ have a linking number 1 in $S^{2n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2n}$). Then a counter example for $D^n\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be obtained by mapping two disjoint sub-balls of $D^n$ to $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively. This map cannot be approximated by embeddings.
Now, my first question is, is this the 'only type' of counter examples? My intuition is that, this construction needs to use all $2n$ dimensions to create the double point which obstructs an approximation by embeddings, so what will happen if we want to approximate a continuous map $f: D^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\text{im}(f)\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}?$ Here let us fix the standard embedding (inclusion) of $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.
More generally, I would like to ask what is the maximal integer $k$ ($<2n$) such that any continuous map $f:D^n\to\mathbb{R}^k\subset\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ can be approximated by topological (or smooth) embeddings $D^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$?
Note a trivial bound is $k \geq n$: If $k=n$, we can take the graph of any continuous function, as an embedding $g: D^n\to D^n\times \mathbb{R}^{n=k}$. (If we want a smooth embedding, I guess we can first perturb the continuous map to a smooth map and then perform this construction?) Then we can embed $D^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ but shrink its radius. In this way we get an embedding that can approximate the original continuous function with arbitrary small error.
